# Adding header/footer in php (beginner level query)

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, header, footer

How do we write files that are included in a php webpage using `includes` or `requires`.

 (1)Is there any programming convention for the stuff?
For example: Do you add title in the header/footer file or not? if yes won't there be two titles one from the file included and one of the file that is including the footer/header file. What about bootstrap/js files do I include them in header/footer file or not? Because header/footer contain the usage of bootstrap classes.Won't importing them again and again increase the loading time of pages? 
 (2)So basically  do we add head section? if yes how do these values affect the current document?

As I am just beginner I would be glad if you could share some example that has html and php code in the file that gets included. Along with bit of explanation regarding the questions above (1&2). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of asking about `includes` or `requires` for rendering conventions I would suggest you learn how does a "Render Engine" works. For example Twig (from Symfony), Blade (from Laravel) or Mustache.

Basically, because you should want to distinguish between the different layers in your system. The rendering layer should not contain any other logic but rendering.

The easiest approach here, especially if you're new, is to go with the MVC (Model-View-Controller). And from there you can escalate the structure.

**The answer for this question "Adding header or footer in php" is basically [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) or [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade).**

Comment: @AshishKumar please search in google before posting in StackOverflow, Thanks!!